# Sudoku puzzle #1

Tags: sudoku

Please solve the following sudoku puzzle (from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sudoku_Puzzle_by_L2G-20050714_standardized_layout.svg)):

[image: sudoku]

Comment: If this is not your own creation, standard procedure here is to provide information regarding the source of the puzzle.

Comment: This puzzle was [taken from Wikipedia without credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sudoku_Puzzle_by_L2G-20050714_standardized_layout.svg): because of this, it is plagiarism and has been removed.

Comment: @Randal'Thor has kindly edited in a link to the original source of the puzzle. Note that that source -- the Wikipedia page about sudoku -- *already contains a solution to the puzzle, right next to the puzzle itself, so it's really hard to see how this question (even once solved) will actually add any value to PSE or to the world.

Answer (score 1):

There are sudokus with multiple results.I think this is your dilema. For more read [this](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Mahmood/More.html)

[image: Sudoku with multiple solutions]

Comment: Bottom middle in the bottom right is a 7

Comment: @hexomino That works well with either 1 or 7. I left it that way to show the possibility. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I mean in the original puzzle it's given as a 7.

Comment: @hexomino ohh my bad, i will remove the answer after you acknowledge this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one solution

```
534 678 912
672 195 348
198 342 567

859 761 423
426 853 791
713 924 856

961 537 284
287 419 635
345 286 179
```

Comment: No there are not. The other answer missed the 7 in r9c8 from the original board. When you include that 7 the problem has only one solution.